# Rijndael Encryption/Decryption Throws Exceptions

Tags: c#, encryption

When I try to encrypt using AES, I get the error `Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string` when i try to execute this line of code:

```
byte[] clearBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(clearText);
```

Here is my code:

```
public string AESEncrypt( string clearText )
{
  clearText = HttpUtility.UrlEncode( clearText ) ; 
  byte[] clearBytes = Convert.FromBase64String( clearText ) ;
  byte[] ivBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( InitV );
  byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( EncryptionKey ) ;

  var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
  symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
  symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

  var enctryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes);

  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using ( CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream( ms, enctryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write ) )
    {
      cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
      cs.Close();
    }
    clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
  }

  return clearText;
}
```

Alternately, when I try to decrypt, I get the error `The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.` trying to execute this line of code:

```
byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
```

Here is my code:

```
public string AESDecrypt(string cipherText)
{
  string clearText;

  cipherText = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cipherText) ;

  byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
  byte[] ivBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(InitV);
  byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncryptionKey);

  var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
  symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
  symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

  var enctryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes);

  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, enctryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    {
      cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
      cs.Close();
    }
    clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
  }

  return clearText;
}
```

Comment: Always indicate the programming language in your questions. Otherwise they won't be seen easily, and auto syntax highlighting won't be applied either.

Comment: Don't substantially edit your question. If you think your original question is not valid anymore, delete it or something, but never substantially alter it (especially after it has been answered).

Comment: Moi, please don't add tags to the title at all, tagging the question with the appropriate ones is enough.

Comment: Could you maybe edit the title to the problem in the *currently posted code* to reflect the problem? Maybe you could then post a new question with a working example? I think we've given you quite a few hints on how to create a better question. I think the current question is not very useful as it seems you added the `URLEncode` part as an afterthought and then ran into another issue.

Comment: thank you I'm pretty new at this but i will take all comments into account next time

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what makes you think that URL encode generates base 64 encoded bytes, but decoding it will usually result in the errors that you are getting.

```
    cipherText = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cipherText);
    byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
```

is just absolute nonsense. Please look up what these functions do and try again.

Comment: thanks fr the advice

Comment: Sorry to be a bit blunt in the answer. URLEncode replaces non-URL friendly characters, which base 64 is a character encoding for byte arrays. As said, completely different from each other.

Comment: i know what it does i didnt want to start some childish fight... i only added that because i saw a blog that suggested it, i got it working buy removing that and getting the UTF representation of clear text but the decryption is not showing what the encryption was put in.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing your base64 encoded string on the QueryString? If so it likely contains "+" signs which are not valid data on the QueryString. URL Encode your base 64 string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: to be clear right now this method takes a static "123456789" as a test .....